# Rails - adding item to subject of email if checkbox selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, mailer

I'm trying to add "URGENT!" to the beginning of my subject in a email being sent as a confirmation when a form is submitted and the 'Urgent' checkbox is checked.

I basically can't figure out how to find out if the value of the checkbox is "true" or "false".

The checkbox is stored in my **Tickets** Model under :urgent_reminder column.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my `Newticket_Mailer.rb`:

```
class NewticketMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "ExampleFrom@Email.org"

def urgent
  if @ticket.urgent_reminder == true
    puts "URGENT!"
  else 
  end
end

def email_subjectCreation
  urgent 'Facilities Ticket Created for ' + @ticket.school.name
end

def ticket_creation(ticket)
  @ticket = ticket
  mail to: @ticket.mailing_list.name, subject: email_subjectCreation, reply_to:   @ticket.submitter.full_email
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing to stdout. Try something closer to:

```
def urgent
  'URGENT: ' if @ticket.urgent_reminder
end

def subject
  "#{urgent}Facilities Ticket Created for #{@ticket.school.name}"
end
```

I'd probably make the accessor more Ruby-esque, however:

```
def urgent
  'URGENT: ' if @ticket.urgent?
end
```

Comment: You are a fabulous human being. This works perfectly and also showed me a better way to do it.  Thank you so much.